# How to add details automatically of server host into variable/file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

In `/home/user/.ssh/` `known_host` file we can get all details of host server name.

```
Ex - hostname.abcs.com,129.167.29.11 ssh.rsa <encryption-key>
```

Shell script like -

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=$1
IP_ADDR=$2
ENC_TYP=$3
KEY=$4
.........
```

Then need to add hostname details in 1st variable (HOST), IP address in 2nd variable, encryption type & encryption key into variables. Ex-

```
[] > cat HOST
```

then output as `hostname.abcs.com`

```
[] > cat IP_ADDR
```

then output as `129.167.29.11`

or we can also add all these details in 1 file as `hostname.txt`. So i need to add in shell script to add server host details automatically in file or in variable.

Comment: There are a lot of problems here. First, it is very hard to understand your English. Second, the structure of the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` doesn't correspond to your description. Third, for outputting the value of a variable, you don't have to issue `cat IP_ADDR` but `echo $IP_ADDR`. The question you have is probably: "How do I read several values, separated by a comma, on a line and put these in separate variables?".

Comment: The hostnames may be in the first column, but the first column may also be `@revoked` or `@cert-authority`, in which case the hostnames is in the second column. In either case, the hostnamescolumn is a comma-separated list of patterns, which may contain an IP address, or it may not.   Do you have a consistent known_hosts file in which every line has `name,ip-addr` as the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostnames may be in the first column, but the first column may also be `@revoked` or `@cert-authority`, in which case the hostnames is in the second column.  We will ignore that issue for now, and assume you do not have any lines like that.  (If you do, you can probably easily filter them out with awk.)

*If* your file is such that the first entry of every line is of the form `name,ip_address`, you could get away with something as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=' ,' read name ip_addr key_type b64_enc_key comment; do
        if ! test "$name" = "${name#@}"; then
                echo "WARNING: unexpected marker $name found" >&2
                continue
        fi
        # more validation is a good idea
        echo host = "$name"
        echo ip = "$ip_addr"
        echo type = "$key_type"
        echo key = "$b64_enc_key"
done < known_hosts
```

but note that the hostnames field may be only one entry (ie, it does not contain any commas) or it may be more than 2 (ie, it contains more than 1 comma) in which case all of these column counts will be wrong and the fields will be in the wrong variables.  You should ensure the validity of the data much more carefully than is done above!

Comment: Did you consider `IFS=" ,"` ?

Comment: @WalterA I did not, but that works very well in this case.   Thanks for the excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer for reading several values, separated by a comma or a space, from an input line and put these in separate variables is using next command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=", " read HOST IP_ADDR ENC_TYP KEY 
  do 
    # for each line in the input file, do something
    echo HOST=$HOST IP_ADDR=$IP_ADDR etc.
  done < /home/user/.ssh/known_host
```

as far as input your file `/home/user/.ssh/known_host` matches what you said.